# How to display the newest information at the top of the list and the old one at Bottom

Tags: python, json, firebase, flask

I just want to ask what should I use and do to be able to do what I have in mind.

For example, from the current firebase values which when extracted becomes Json I can get this:

[image]

Through this code:

```
   result1 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/' + currentdate + '/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/', None)
    result2 = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/' + currentdate + '/Inspection/Scan-out/Inspector/', None)

for key in result1.keys():
       inspector = key
    timeout = result2[inspector]["Time"]



    result1datetime = firebase.get('/Rooms/Room1/'+ currentdate +'/Inspection/Scan-in/Inspector/'+ inspector +'/', None)





    for key in result1datetime.keys():
        key = sorted(result1datetime.keys())[-2]
        time = key
        print time



    print time

    ch1 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Entrance louver clean and dust-free"]
    # ch2 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Room plat number – clean and well-polished"]
    ch3 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Appearance door surface- in good condition"]
     ch4 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Let the door close by itself to test the door closure – in working order"]
    ch5 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Eye viewer and fire escape plan in order"]
    ch6 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Privacy Sign or Make Up Room Sign"]
     ch7 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Key card holder – in working order"]
    ch8 = result1datetime[time]["Checklist"]["Switches at the entrance working correctly"]
```

This is working but what I wanted to do was when the database gets an update. A new input like the one in the picture would be on top of the last input at its bottom

For example:

```
Scan-in: 2017-12-06
Time: Dec 6, 2017 4:58:00 AM
Time-out: Dec 5, 2017 4:58:21 AM
Inspection time: -1 day, 23:59:39
Inspector: trhf
Checklist: 

Scan-in: 2017-12-05
Time: Dec 5, 2017 4:58:00 AM
Time-out: Dec 5, 2017 4:58:21 AM
Inspection time: -1 day, 23:59:39
Inspector: trhf
Checklist:
```

Ive been searching for ways to accomplish this, but I'm clueless. if you were me how would you implement this? and what libraries would you be using? Thankyou very much! Any help is very very very appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking how to display the newest information at the top of the list instead of at the bottom?

Comment: @jay yes I think that's what she meant